# wordpress page shows echo only

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I downloaded all the files of a wordpress site from the server and putt it in one folder . I change the base url and database credential and whole website start working , but whenever i want to access any page it shows me only.

```
 echo
```

and nothing more and i cant not able to login to wp-admin as it shows echo there too . I search on internet and it says permalinks issue , but i can not able to login through wp-admin . If i  delete the .htacess file and now it shows 404 Error .

Comment: Most likely your PHP dev environment differ with this on the production server.
Rename your theme folder on the server. Be sure that you uploaded WP's default theme(most likely twentyfourteen). Refresh the page. If page loads normaly, then there is omething wrong with your theme. If not, then start renaming plugin's folders. Refresh after each rename. This should help you to identify the origin of the problem.

Comment: @BorisBelenski i did this on localhost

Comment: So? Then it's the other way around. You have 2 different environments that seems to have different configurations. I asume that the problem is that you don't have short php tag enabled on your local machine, but you have to check this by your own. Info on the problem is too scanty. See what is in the php log. Also what you did try?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by accessing direct to the database and updating the value

wordpress table name

```
 wp_option
```

search for permalink_structure and make its value null . As i can not able to access this through the wp-admin .